# How to get multiple elements by name in XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've the below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<TestSuite>
  <TestCase Name="XXX" ID="123;234; 345; 456">
    <CodeBlock />
  </TestCase>
  <TestCase Name="East" ID="11,22,33, 44, 55">
    <CodeBlock />
  </TestCase>
</TestSuite>
```

I need to get all the ID and order them by ID ASC, below is my Linq:

```
var r = (from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("TestCase")
         select new { ID = lv1.Attribute("ID").Value })
        .Where(d => d.ID != string.Empty)
        .GroupBy(l => l.ID)
        .ToList();
```

I now get:

```
123;234; 345; 456
11,22,33, 44, 55
```

But how can I get the IDs like:

```
11
22
33
44
55
123
234
345
456
```

Comment: Is ID Int type or string type ??

Comment: string type, since some ID may be string

Comment: It is very accurate that you have included the xml of yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear why you're grouping at all... and you just need to split the values and flatten that with [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), by the looks of it:

```
var separators = new[] { ';', ',' };
var r = xdoc.Descendants("TestCase")
            .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("ID"))
            .Where(ids => ids != null)
            .SelectMany(ids => ids.Split(separators,
                                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .Select(id => int.Parse(id.Trim()))
            .OrderBy(id => id)
            .ToList();
```

Note that I've parsed each ID as integer, on the grounds that if you treat them just as strings, then "123" comes before "55". If they're *actually* not necessarily integers, but you want to sort any values which can be parsed as integers that way, then the ordering part becomes trickier.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
var r = (from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("TestCase")
        select new { ID = lv1.Attribute("ID").Value }).
        Where(d => d.ID != string.Empty).OrderBy(l => int.Parse(l.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format, "123;234; 345; 456"

Comment: that's the right idea.. now just change the last OrderBy(l => int.Prase(l.ID.ToString().Replace(";", "")))  ...
+1

Comment: I'm puzzled, l.ID.ToString().Replace(";", "") returns string,how can it be parsed to int?

Comment: Yes it will return string without the semi colon. That can be parsed into integer